# Docker for local development with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat, docker-volume

I want to use docker with a spring boot application in my development environment.

For production I first generate the war file using `mvn package` then I build an image using this dockerfile :

```
FROM tomcat:9.0-jre8-alpine

COPY target/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/api.war
```

But for dev purpose I want to be able to check my changes when I edit my code and not have to redo `mvn package` then build the image then run the container. Changes made to the code can be watched using spring boot devtools so that my app is recompiled every time I make changes to the source code.

But then I thought to use an image, still with tomcat, and setup a volume. But I don't know which files I have to watch. Is it the folder target or some specific files inside it ? And to which folder inside my image do I link the volume to ? Something like $CATALINA_HOME/webapps I presume.

If anyone can help me to point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated ? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use Docker here and not the native Spring tools you reference?

Comment: Because I use docker for my prod environment so for consistency I want to use docker in dev

Comment: It makes sense to run integration tests with a locally-built Docker image.  But there's no requirement that, if you're going to deploy into Docker (or AWS, or Kubernetes) that you must do all of your development in the identical environment.  An ordinary local Java build environment will be much easier to work with for day-to-day work.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using a [Maven Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven). mapping the source code using volumes, and setting the working directory so Maven can find the pom.xml. In your docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  backend:
    image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
    command: mvn spring-boot:run
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8085:8085
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/mymaven:rw
    working_dir: /usr/src/mymaven
```

Make sure you have the boot tools enabled in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

And if you need, enable the remote debugger:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <jvmArguments>
      -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8085
    </jvmArguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then you can **attach** your code editor to the Docker container:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations